# Multiple adress parameters in single page application

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Sorry for the long post. My code is corrected by a bot and I get an error returned that I can't seem to work my way around.

In my code, I want to make so that you can you can visit `#two`-adress, followed two separate parameters like this: `#/two/hello/world` which generates `<div>helloworld</div>`.

This is my Vue code:

```
let One = Vue.component('one', {
  template: '<h1>One {{ $route.params.user }} </h1>'
})

let Two = Vue.component('two', {
  template: '<h1>Two</h1>'
})

let router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
    component: One,
    path: '/one/:user'
  }, {
    component: One,
    path: '/one'
  }, 
  {
    component: Two,
    path: '/two/'
  }, 
]})


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: router
})
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="app">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><router-link to="/one/test">test</router-link></li>
          <li><router-link to="two/hello/world">helloworld</router-link></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
```

I get returned this output from the bot:

```
index.html
    ✓ exists
  index.js
    ✓ exists
    ✓ is valid JavaScript
  index.html and index.js
    ✓ constant or variable One has the name "one"
    ✓ constant or variable Two has the name "two"
    ✓ navigating to #/ does not render "One"
    ✓ navigating to #/ does not render "Two"
    ✓ navigating to #/one renders "One"
    ✓ navigating to #/one does not render "Two"
    ✓ navigating to #/two renders "Two"
    ✓ navigating to #/two does not render "One"
    ✓ navigating to #/one/test renders "test"
    ✓ navigating to some other "one" address renders something else
    ✓ navigating to #/two/hello/world renders "helloworld"
    FAIL) navigating to some other "two" address renders something else
```

The last line/error is the problem. What's wrong with my code? I've tried to clone the `two`-component but I get the same output...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to use dynamic segments in your route, where the data in the route is passed along as data to your component. [You can take a look at the Vue Router documentation for dynamic route matching here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html).

In short, you need to redefine your route:

```
let router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
  // other routes
  {
    component: Two,
    path: '/two/:first/:second'
  }, 
]})
```

Note that `:first` and `:second` can be anything you'd like. It could just as easily be:

```
  {
    component: Two,
    path: '/two/:zebra/:canteloupe'
  },
```

However you choose to name those dynamic route segments, Vue router will pass them along as `params` to your identified component, which in this case is the `Two` component.

So, in your `Two` template, you could do something like...

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{$route.params.first}}{{$route.params.second}}
  <div>
<template>
```